# How can I delete only the selected row, when having several cells with the same ID?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, t-sql, stored-procedures

I was setting a stored procedure to delete a specific row based on the option that the user picks. The stored procedure recived 2 id and check if they are in the table. But i can´t figure it out. Can you help?

My stored procedure looks like this

```sql
@idcliente numeric,
@codmedia numeric
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON; 
    IF (EXISTS(SELECT COD_MEDIA FROM MEIOS_CLIENTES WHERE ID_CLIENTE = @idcliente AND COD_MEDIA = @codmedia))
    BEGIN
        DELETE FROM MEIOS_CLIENTES WHERE ID_CLIENTE = @idcliente AND COD_MEDIA = @codmedia
    END     
END
```

The table in the database looks like this

```
COD_SERVICO | ID_CLIENTE
     1            2
     26           2
     1            1
     32           1
```

The table has alot of records.

Imagine if user picks to delete COD_SERVICO 1 from ID_CLIENTE 2.

**EDIT:**

I'm doing the request of the action by jquery, the code looks like this:

```
function removeMeioCliente(idcliente ,idservico) {


    bootbox.dialog({
        message: "Irá eliminar o serviço selecionado. Deseja continuar?",
        title: "Alerta - Eliminação do Serviço",
        buttons: {

            danger: {
                label: "Cancelar",
                className: "btn-danger",
                callback: function () {
                }
            }, success: {
                label: "Continuar",
                className: "btn-success",
                callback: function () {

                    var options = {
                        url: baseurlrequest + 'cliente/deleteservico',
                        params: {
                            id2: idcliente,
                            id: idservico,
                        },
                        onsuccess: displaydeleteservico
                    }

                    $.fn.ajaxpostjson(options);

                }
            }
        }
    });
}


function displaydeleteservico(data) {
    if (data.status == 200) {
        toastr.info("Serviço eliminado com sucesso!", 'Cision Corpora');
    }

    if (data.status == 500) {
        toastr.error(data.html, 'Cision Corpora');
    }
}
```

In my view my table looks like this. The item is to string because i was testing if some ID's was being passed, both are null.

```
       <table class="table table-striped" cellspacing="0">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th class="th-sm">Meios do Cliente</th>
                                    <th></th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            <tbody>

                                @foreach (var item in Model.Meios)
                                {
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            @Html.Raw(item.Item3)
                                        </td>
                                        <td onclick="removeMeioCliente(@item.Item1.ToString(),@item.Item2.ToString());"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></td>
                                    </tr>
                                }
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

Why are both ID's null?

**EDIT 2:**

I dit it!

I will post the code if someone want's to know the solution.

In my view the code looks like this

```
 <td><a id="servicoidcliente" data-id="@item.Item1" onclick="removeMeioCliente(@item.Item2);"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a></td>
```

And in Jquery added a simple line:

```
var idcliente = $('#servicoidcliente').data("id");
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult DeleteServico(string id2,string id)
        {
            var statusreq = this.StatusOk;
            var html = "";    
            try
            {
               BusinessService.Cliente.RemoverServicoCliente(id2,id);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                statusreq = this.StatusError;
                html = ex.Message;
            }
            return Json(new
            {
                id = id,
                id2 = id2
            },
            JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow - could you specify which dbms you are using (MySQL, SQL Server etc.)

Answer (score 0):

This should work, what is your issue ?

You could however omit the "if" part, If there is no match for your WHERE condition delete will do nothing, but not fail.

Comment: It's working when i execute it mannualy, Im using c# asp.net mvc, how can i pass 2 id's to a stored procedure?

Comment: @DanielOliveira please create a new question for your MVC related issue - you are asking something different than what you have specified in this question.

Comment: I was asking for help in general but ok.

Comment: @DanielOliveira Do you need a stored procedure, or just a solution?  I posted a basic solution, but can adjust that to make a stored procedure.  Will the table your targeting always be the same or have the same name?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a variable to accept user input and remove the selected column based on what the COD_SERVICO value is.

```
-- Create demonstration table
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#_test') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #_test
CREATE TABLE #_test (
    [ID] INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [COD_SERVICO] VARCHAR(25) NULL,
    [ID_CLIENTE] VARCHAR(25) NULL,
)
INSERT INTO #_test ([COD_SERVICO], [ID_CLIENTE])
VALUES ('1','2'),
        ('26','2'),
        ('45','1'),
        ('32','1')
```

Table values (with ID column):

```
ID  COD_SERVICO ID_CLIENTE
1     1           2
2     26          2
3     45          1
4     32          1


-- Declare variable for input
DECLARE @_cod_servico_to_remove VARCHAR(25)

-- Set variable to whatever the user wants to remove.  This will impact the COD_SERVICO column
SET @_cod_servico_to_remove = '1'

-- Run your delee query (Transact-SQL)
DELETE FROM #_test
WHERE [COD_SERVICO] = @_cod_servico_to_remove
```

Result:

```
ID  COD_SERVICO ID_CLIENTE
2     26             2
3     45             1
4     32             1
```

EDIT: Here's a procedure that is largely the same as OP's, but considers missing values.

```
--Clear any prior procedures
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.RemoveRecords') AND OBJECTPROPERTY(id,  N'IsProcedure') = 1) DROP PROCEDURE dbo.RemoveRecords;
GO

--Set two variables to null; Evaluate passed arguments inside the procedure.
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.RemoveRecords
    @idcliente FLOAT = NULL,
    @codmedia FLOAT = NULL
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET XACT_ABORT ON;

    DECLARE @_sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

    IF @idcliente IS NOT NULL AND @codmedia IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN
            IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MEIOS_CLIENTES WHERE CONVERT(FLOAT, ID_CLIENTE) = @idcliente AND CONVERT(FLOAT, COD_MEDIA) = @codmedia) > '0'
                BEGIN
                    DELETE FROM MEIOS_CLIENTES
                    WHERE CONVERT(FLOAT, [ID_CLIENTE]) = @idcliente
                    AND CONVERT(FLOAT, [COD_SERVICO]) = @codmedia
                END;
        END;

END;
GO
```

Comment: It will be the same table everytime, but how will this work if the table is filled with more than 1000 rows?

Comment: The table is showing what services the client has associated with him. I don't know if I'm taking the right path here doing a stored procedure.

Comment: So, you would need to have both values (client and service) not be null in order to remove the correct row, right?  Otherwise, the procedure shouldn't run.

Comment: I updated the question with more info, you can check it out if you want